# How to generate this method in a class using codemodel?

Tags: java, selenium, code-generation

How to generate this method in a class using codemodel?
using selenium jar.

```
 public void clickLink(String cssSelector) {
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(""));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void clickLink(String cssSelector) {
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector));
        element.click();
 }
```

Comment: Hiya there! While this may actually answer the question, not everyone is as knowledgeable as you are. Mind adding a little explanation? Thanks!